# Distcc with C++ undefined reference

Tags: c++, g++, undefined-reference, distcc

I having trouble configuring distcc to compile C++ files. I did a standard small ["Hello, World" program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program) in C++ and am trying to get distcc to compile it locally (before I get fancy with a larger project), but I am getting "undefined reference" errors.

My program, called "hello.cpp":

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  std::cout << "Hello World in c++" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

My command:

```
$ distcc hello.cpp
```

Terminal output:

```
/tmp/cc5rZwhV.o: In function `main': <br>
hello.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `std::cout' <br>
hello.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)' <br>
hello.cpp:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)' <br>
hello.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))' <br>
/tmp/cc5rZwhV.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)': <br>
hello.cpp:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()' <br>
hello.cpp:(.text+0x59): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()' <br>
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status <br>
distcc[21053] ERROR: compile hello.cpp on localhost failed <br>
```

Other information:

This program compiles just fine with g++ and C++. A similar program written in C using `printf` works with distcc.

Output of `$ distcc --version`:

```
distcc 3.2rc1 x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  (protocols 1, 2 and 3) (default port 3632)
  built Jul  7 2014 13:18:34
....(copyright stuff)
```

Comment: perhaps -lstdc++ flag can help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `-lstdc++` to your linker command line (that is, add `libstdc++` to your linked libraries explicitly, which normally `g++` would do for you).

While you're at it, try `icecc` as well.  I personally prefer it.